# Unable to complete Input for Scanner

Tags: java, input, console

I am working on a program to average grades. For some reason my scanner or console is not letting me enter an answer for the third question and I am not sure why.

A lot of the code is commented out as it unneeded for now.

edit: I am not sure how to number lines of code here but the lines 23-28 I think are the problem

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

int count = 0;
double grade = 0;
//decided to use double for grade in case user's want to be specific with
//decimal points.
String user;
boolean enter;
String name;
String enterAgain;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
name = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter a grade: ");
grade = userInput.nextDouble();

//System.out.println(user); //May not need this line
System.out.println("Would you like to continue entering grades? (y/n)");
enterAgain = userInput.nextLine();

if (enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        /*|| enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))*/ {

    System.out.println("Please enter another grade: "); }
/*  if (user.getScore() > highScore) {

        highScore = user.getScore();
    }
    System.out.println("High Score: "
            + DecimalFormat.format(grade));
    user.setScore(0);
}*/

else {
    enter = false;
userInput.close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the link that @Fast Snail commented ([Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)) - it explains your issue. To fix this problem, as shown in that post, add a `userInput.nextLine()` after the `userInput.nextDouble()`. Here would be the finished code (I removed some of the comments and variables that weren't relevant):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GradeData{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double grade = 0;
        String name;
        String enterAgain;
        boolean enter = true; //to use in while loop
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        name = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a grade: ");
        grade = userInput.nextDouble(); 
        userInput.nextLine() //add this to your program
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue entering grades? (y/n)");
    enterAgain = userInput.nextLine(); 

        while(enter){
            if(enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                System.out.println("Please enter another grade: ");
                /*enterAgain = userInput.nextLine() - we want user to input 
                a double grade, not a String*/
                grade = userInput.nextDouble();
            }
            else if(enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                System.out.println("Ok. Don't enter more grades.");
                break; 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can only enter (y/n)");
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `break;` statements in the else{} statements are to stop the loop from running after the user has entered n for no (or some other random character besides y or n). For example, the loop will output "Ok. Don't enter more grades." and stop there. If we don't include the `break;` statement, it'll print that out infinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your help, those edits worked nicely. Do you happen to know a good loop that would work with that if statement?

Comment: @Martin yes. Look at my updated code. It allows the user to keep entering grades after they entered y for yes. I was trying to make it so that they can enter n and exit the loop after they've already entered y - but that didn't work out. Still trying to figure that out. So pretty much after you enter y, you keep getting asked to enter grades without being able to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from my experience this seems to be a fairly difficult problem to get around based off of your code. I have found one solution to getting to the if statement after the "continue entering grades?" question. set the enterAgain variable equal to userInput.next(); This will allow the program to continue its path. Though, from there, I had an issue where after you say "y or n" the program ends. Here:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to continue entering grades? (y/n)");
enterAgain = userInput.next();
```

This code will allow you to enter something but it does not display "Please enter another grade." This was the only solution I was able to come up with. Also try using a switch statement or while loop to experiment results in your program. Best of luck.